# M1911 Model material issues

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials

[image]

So from the image above(or below) you can see that the slide on my M1911 is grey while the sights and the front area of the slide are still the standard mesh white. I don't know why this is happening. The front and the sights are joined together with the slide and they've all been smart UV unwrapped. The slide has a grey color because that's the color I set for it in the nodes. But it's just the front and the sights that I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have different materials assigned, got to the materials tab in object properties to see your materials.

When in edit mode you should see options to assign selected vertices to materials, you can use this to assign everything to the correct material slot. You can also use the select options here to see which vertices are currently assigned to that material.